# Relative pronouns replace “ich” or “du”

Tags: personal-pronoun, relative-clause

I am learning German relative clauses and I got stuck on how to replace personal pronouns such as *ich, du,* etc.

For example in the sentence:

> **Der Mann** war 25 Jahre alt. **Der Mann** war nicht im Ausland gewesen.
>
> **Der Mann, der** nicht im Ausland gewesen war, war 25 Jahre alt.

But I couldn’t find a resource to replace in a sentence like this:

> Ich war 25 Jahre alt. Ich war vorher nicht im Ausland gewesen.
>
> Ich, ___ vorher nicht im Ausland gewesen war, war 25 Jahre alt.

The table I got, doesn’t cover this:

```
            Masculine    Feminine    Neuter     Plural
Nominative  der          die         das        die
Accusative  den          die         das        die
Dative      dem          der         dem        denen
Genitive    dessen       deren       dessen     deren
```

Comment: Welcome to the site and thank your for your interesting question. I edited it a bit to remove some errors unrelated to your issue. I do hope it still retains your intent. If not just roll back :)

Comment: @Takkat I'm afraid you already included the answer ;-)

Comment: @MartinSchwehla: sorry for the confusion, I had no idea you already were at an answer. Still, the original examples had too many issues distracting from the main question, i.e. how to relate to a personal pronoun in a relative clause. These issues had to be removed to allow a clear answer. I don't think we should focus on telling how we could word the examples better (this would make another question) but rather should offer a solution to the single issue asked asked here (which I did not include in my edits).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. Use the same pronouns as for the third person and also use the third person for the relative clause’s verb:

   > Ich, der/die rote Haare hat, bin 25 Jahre alt.
   >   Du, der/die rote Haare hat, bist 25 Jahre alt.
   >   Wir, die rote Haare haben, sind 25 Jahre alt.
   >   Ihr, die rote Haare haben, seid 25 Jahre alt.

   This is rather unusual for the second person, in particular in plural.
2. Use the same pronouns as for the third person, followed by the nominative of the regular pronoun for the first (or second) person. Use the first (or second) person for the verb:

   > Ich, der/die ich rote Haare habe, bin 25 Jahre alt.
   >   Du, der/die du rote Haare hast, bist 25 Jahre alt.
   >   Wir, die wir rote Haare haben, sind 25 Jahre alt.
   >   Ihr, die ihr rote Haare habt, seid 25 Jahre alt.

   This always works well, and I would consider it strongly preferrable for the second person.

Comment: Furthermore, I disagree in one point: For the second person version 1 is the better choice to my mind.

Comment: @Em1: Interesting. I had to go through some examples to ensure that it’s really correct.

Comment: I would've said that variant 1 is the colloquial version; however, probably it's just another regional thing.

Answer (score 5):

The first pair of examples should be transformed to:

> Der Mann war 25 Jahre alt und war noch nie im Ausland (gewesen).
>
> Der Mann, *der noch nie im Ausland gewesen war,* war 25 Jahre alt.

If you want to use a subordinate clause, it is much better to embed it into the main clause because only then the two statements get their proper weight and emphasis within the sentence.

> Ich war 25 Jahre alt. Ich war noch nie zuvor im Ausland gewesen.
>
> Ich war *mit meinen 25 Jahren* noch nie im Ausland gewesen.

There's no use adding a clause led by a pronoun when the subject of the main clause is the narrator himself, save the subject is equated with another noun:

> Ich war *ein 25-Jähriger, der* noch nie im Ausland gewesen war.
>
> Ich, *der ich noch nie im Ausland gewesen war,* war 25 Jahre alt.

To see my point just try to translate your sentences into English and French:

I was 25 years old, who never had been abroad. ??

J'étais 25 ans qui n'avait jamais été à l'étranger. ??

The solution is you have to find the proper structure to reveal the relationship between your statements. It makes no sense to just string them together.

Comment: Das ist eine Grammatikübung! Natürlich kann man über die Sinnhaftigkeit einer Verknüpfung der beiden Beispielsätze streiten (es ließe sich aber sicher ein passender Kontext konstruieren), aber es wäre hilfreicher, zumindest einen geeigneteren Beispielsatz zur Frage vorzuschlagen. Und: auf Englisch würde ich schreiben "I, who had never been abroad, was 25 years old"...und auch hier ließe sich z.B. ergänzen ..."and about to emigrate to Argentina."

Comment: @Stephie Die Frage wurde bearbeitet, sodass das ursprüngliche 2. Beispiel nicht mehr so deutlich ist und meine Antwort ein bisschen in der Luft hängt, es lautete: "Ich war 25 Jahre alt, der noch nie im Ausland war". Darauf beziehen sich auch die Übersetzungen.

Comment: Ich hatte auch die Originalversion gesehen - ich denke, der Kern der Frage ist eigentlich nur "wie ersetze ich das 'ich' im Relativsatz".

Comment: @Stephie Stimmt, und die vom OP ursprünglich vorgeschlagene Lösung musste richtiggestellt werden.